# Excel COUNTA ignoring errors and certain values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula which I need to count only values NOT errors.

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$4:$B$2000,($E$4:$E$2000<=10))))
```

This COUNTA calculates as the following, if FILTER returns nothing, which is *1*:

```
=COUNTA(#VALUE!)
```

Is there any workaround for this, so that the count be *0* not *1*? The solution entails ignoring *errors* or *certain values.*

*This [blog post](https://exceljet.net/formulas/count-cells-that-contain-errors) greatly helped.

Comment: What about counting everything and then substract couting only errors? so final output would be counting values. am I right?

Comment: What exactly does "certain values" mean in this context?

Comment: Are you aware of `=ISERROR()`?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a construct that would actually return an error. Instead of `COUNTA()` which would include errors, just use `ROWS()` and if this would error out, `IFERROR()` will return 0:

```
=IFERROR(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$4:$B$2000,$E$4:$E$2000<=10))),)
```

Comment: Actually the following formula worked and your response matters.

```=SUMPRODUCT(--ISTEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$4:$B$2000,$E$4:$E$2000<=10))))```

Comment: @FighterJet, great to hear. If it answered your question, consider to accept it as such and click the checkmark to the left of it.